# How to disable checkbox after change in another field in django template?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, frontend

I'm junior backend python dev (Django) but I have to do "easy" frontend task.
I think it is easy but not for me because my frontend ends on F :(

**I'm using bootstrap in this app.**

I have a form field with some fields, two of them are checkbox named **'checkbox_1'**
and number field for price named **'price_1'**.

Checkbox on True means "Product is free" so...

If checkbox_1 is True, field of 'price_1' should go disabled so I can't write on it.
If 'price_1' is 0 and 'checkbox_1' is False, than it shows a message "Price can't be 0 if product is not free".

I have tried with django templates using if statement like this:

```
<form action="index.html" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">{{ form.price.label }} </label>
        {{ form.price }} EUR
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox m-b-14">
        <label>{{ form.free_product }} <i>/</i> {{ form.free_product.label }}</label>

        <!--AND HERE IS MY TRY-->
        {% if form.price.value == 0 %}
            TEST Price 0
        {% else %}
            TEST price is bigger than 0
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</form>
```

It works only after first enter the page. 
I think I have to use JS? Or maybe there is possibility to do it in bootstrap or django templates?

Even if my example would work I still don't know how to pass "required" or "disabled", at runtime... in the moment that You click on checkbox.

That's black magic for me I event don't know how to search for it correctly ;/

Can you please help me what I can do here to make it work?

I will be extremely grateful...

Comment: Yes, you will need JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do it with django, because django have syncronous call... so to you get any response from django again you need make a new request or refresh your page... since you need something dinamic, you should use Javascript to do that.

```
document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = !this.checked;
};

<input type="text" id="yourText" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
And where should i put this code? normally in html file between html lines? it will work?

In this project there is one big file app.min.js with loads of functions but bad formatted so it is very hard to read it. Maybe i should put it there?

Comment: You should get my code and adapt to your situation, JS code should be placed in <script> tag in <head> tag of your html or bellow the <footer> check this link https://www.w3schools.com/jS/default.asp

Comment: dont put at app.min.js this is "minified" file, this is not for humans read... minify is the action of get a "human read" file and remove all spaces to make it more lighter, so get more performance, you should create your own javascript file... someFile.js and put your logic there and import it to your project

Comment: Check the link i posted early and study the basics of javascript